# Bukkit Plugin: Listener in the main class

Tags: class, plugins, bukkit, listeners

I'm trying to make a plugin where you type the command /settings and it toggles the boolean set. If set is true, I want it so when players join it says 'hi' to them but if it's 'false' it does nothing. (Btw im the only one who can use the command). I tried making two classes, one the main and the second the listener, But I couldn't access the boolean from the listener class so I tried making it all in one class. When using the code I've provided, everything works except for the PlayerJoinEvent. I either need to work out how to access the boolean from another class or how to fix this.

```
package me.jakegeyer28;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import net.md_5.bungee.api.ChatColor;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{

    public boolean set = true;

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("Done");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info("Done");
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("settings")) {
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            if (player.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("jakegeyer27")) {
            if(set == true) {
                set = false;
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Off");
                }
            else if (set == false) {
                set = true;
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "On");
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
        Player player = e.getPlayer();
        if (set == true) {
        player.sendMessage("hi");
    }
    }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you haven't registered your listener. Even though the listener is your main class you still need to register it in your `onEnable` method with `this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);`.